# calculating dimensions of rotated rectangle for it to to mask original

Tags: geometry

I have two identical rectangles.
I'm wanting to rotate one rectangle by either + or - $30^\circ$ about its center point. Then calculate the dimensions required to stretch the rotated rectangle out equally from its center point to cover the other rectangle completely.

I can calculate the width of rotated rectangle using a square root
I was hoping someone could help with calculating the height required.

I hope the following will help illustrate what I mean; essentially I can't figure out how to calculate the red line.

The length will change dependent on angle and the dimensions of the original rectangle.

[image: Illustrating dimensions]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are corresponences between rotation angle and angles between base and rotated rectangles:

[image]
[Larger version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4HOuV.png)

We can use definitions of sinus and cosinus to find lengths of s, t, u and v segments, assuming that $\alpha\in[0,\frac{\pi}{2}]$, $w>0$ and $h>0$:

$$
\cos\alpha=\frac{s}{w}\Rightarrow s=w\cos\alpha\\
\sin\alpha=\frac{t}{w}\Rightarrow t=w\sin\alpha\\
\cos\alpha=\frac{u}{h}\Rightarrow u=h\cos\alpha\\
\sin\alpha=\frac{v}{h}\Rightarrow v=h\sin\alpha
$$

Finally, lenghts of sides of a rotated rectangle:

$$
w'=v+s=h\sin\alpha+w\cos\alpha\\
h'=t+u=w\sin\alpha+h\cos\alpha
$$